# Enter and display array as objects in local storage

Tags: javascript, json

I need to enter data with a specific product id and save it locally. On clicking the button it saves them to local storage. A single product can have multiple filenames.

In customer, if a customer gives the name of the id, it should display all the file names belonging to the id in a text area.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <title>W3.CSS</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var filename = []
            var productid = []

            function managerClick(){
                console.log("manager", productid);  
                console.log("manager", filename);   

                productid.push(document.getElementById("productId").value);
                filename.push(document.getElementById("names").value);

                localStorage.setItem("filename", JSON.stringify(filename)); 
                localStorage.setItem("productid", JSON.stringify(productid));   

                var result={}
                   productid.map(function(k){
                   result[k]=filename;
                   })
                  console.log(result);         

                console.log("productid",productid); 
                console.log("filename",filename);       
            };
                function customerClick(){
                  console.log("Customer");
                 document.getElementById('myTextarea').value = filename;

             };
            </script>
        <body>
            <div class="w3-card-4 w3-margin" style="width:50%;">         
                 <center>Manager</center>

                <div class="w3-container">
                    Product Id: <input type="text" id="productId"><br></br>
                    File Name: <input type="text" id="names"><br></br>
                    <center><button class="w3-btn w3-dark-grey" onclick="managerClick()">Data Entered</button></center><br>
                </div>

                 <center>Customer</center>

                <div class="w3-container">
                    Product Id: <input type="text" id="CustomerpId"><br></br>               
                    <center>
                        <button class="w3-btn w3-dark-grey" onclick="customerClick()">Click To get filename</button>
                    </center><br>
                    <textarea rows="4" cols="30"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

what i need is 1 product could have multiple files but it should not be visible to other product.
Could some one help me to do it?

```
i tryed like this and i get
```

[image]

filename of product 1 & product 2 are displayed in both products
product 1 should have product 1 file 1,2,3
product 2 should have product 2 file 1,2,3,4

Comment: how do you get this localStorage.getItem("myArray")? It seem like no declared localStorage named myArray?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var productdetail = []

    function managerClick() {

        productdetail.push({ productid: document.getElementById("productId").value, filename: document.getElementById("names").value });


        localStorage.setItem("ProductDetails", JSON.stringify(productdetail));


    };
    function customerClick() {

        var prod = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ProductDetails"))
        var selectedProductID = document.getElementById("CustomerpId").value

        for (var i = 0; i < prod.length; i++) {
            if (prod[i].productid == selectedProductID) {
                document.getElementById('myTextarea').value = document.getElementById('myTextarea').value +" "+prod[i].filename;

                  Console.log(prod[i].filename);
                }
            }
        };
    </script>

        <textarea rows="4" cols="30" id="myTextarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: i am not clear what you want to achieve. if file is associated with product id 1 then i will show for that product only.

Comment: consider productid is an object and filename is an array if i choose 1st product the array of file name must be displayed, if i choose 2nd product array of that second product should be displayed, if i type the 1st id in manager a new filename should be added,and should be displayed in that 1st array id itself not anywhere else

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106363/discussion-between-yokesh-varadhan-and-sagar-patel).